# AutoIT - How to run shell script

Tags: shell, applescript, autoit

I managed to run below shell script code in applescript and the outpur generated correctly.
**Shell Script.**

```
do shell script "mdls 'UAT.pdf' | grep 'kMDItemPageWidth\\|kMDItemPageHeight' | awk '/ = / {for (i = 3; i <= NF; i++) printf \"%s \", $i/72; printf \"\\n\";}'"
```

The script basically, read PDF document properties.

How do I run this in AutoIT. Any reference or advice is highly appreciated.

Comment: For which version(s) of Windows? You're asking for a port to AutoIt, which is a great utility, but have you tried anything yet? You'll have to use the Windows equivalents of mdls (see below), grep and awk, but they're not installed by default on Windows (there are windows versions of grep and awk) ... and there is no mdls ... there is a metadata utility for Win from MS called "Filever", and I don't know how much it can do.

Comment: Do you want to start the script? Or do you want to Shellexecute programms on your windows machine?

Comment: whats the diff? Start and shellexecute program?

Comment: The difference is: a) run the commands as they are programmed above. With the do ... b) port the code to windows/Autoit and run it.

Comment: @chinna_82, you have to either include installers for third-party utilities or hand code in AutoIt. If you haven't made any attempts at coding, you are asking for the code to be done for you, and this isn't really correct stackoverflow protocol. I'd be happy to point you to resources, though. That is what my original comment was for.

Comment: ummm... You want to run Autoit on Mac??

Comment: @Xenobiologist i dont any restriction as long i can run the shell script.

Comment: @CRGreen your reply on `have to either include installers for third-party utilities or hand code in AutoIt.` I'm seeking advice or references here. Not the full code. If you know any installer, let me know so I can explore more. If you know any blog with sample code. Let me know and I will try.

Comment: @Milos Nope. I tried in applescript and it works. I want to run in my Window 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now we're getting somewhere! @chinna_82, This is what I advise. Meaning, this is the way I would do it (I have ported a couple of scripts to AutoIt and built an installer using AutoIt. It's pretty great):

1) The least portable part of this is the mdls command, which is unix/OSX only, there is no Windows version, but there may be Windows alternatives. More on that in a bit....

2) All grep and awk are doing is parsing what mdls returns for output. This can be done in a number of ways, including just coding it in AutoIt. Yes, if I were doing this, I *could* find Windows versions or alternatives to grep and awk (windows grep and gawk, for example), but they are doing relatively simple things, and I might just do that in AutoIt (for learning AutoIt's language, see http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/). It's probably not worth finding the exact Windows versions of grep and awk -- just use AutoIt's own language for that.

Anyway, mdls grabs all the pdf's metadata. It is text like:

```
kMDItemAuthors                 = (
    "Flint, Herbert L. (Herbert Longley), b. 1862"
)
kMDItemContentCreationDate     = 2013-10-16 16:07:51 -0700
kMDItemContentModificationDate = 2013-10-16 16:07:52 -0700
kMDItemContentType             = "com.adobe.pdf"
kMDItemContentTypeTree         = (
    "com.adobe.pdf",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.composite-content",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemCreator                 = "Digitized by the Internet Archive"
kMDItemDisplayName             = "practicalinstruc00flin.pdf"
kMDItemEncodingApplications    = (
    "Recoded by LuraDocument PDF v2.53"
)
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate     = 2013-10-16 16:07:52 -0700
kMDItemFSCreationDate          = 2013-10-16 16:07:51 -0700
kMDItemFSCreatorCode           = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags           = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon         = 0
kMDItemFSInvisible             = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden     = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery          = 0
kMDItemFSLabel                 = 0
kMDItemFSName                  = "practicalinstruc00flin.pdf"
kMDItemFSNodeCount             = 0
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID          = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID           = 501
kMDItemFSSize                  = 12668272
kMDItemFSTypeCode              = ""
kMDItemKeywords                = (
    "http://archive.org/details/practicalinstruc00flin"
)
kMDItemKind                    = "PDF"
kMDItemLastUsedDate            = 2013-10-30 20:00:54 -0700
kMDItemNumberOfPages           = 210
kMDItemPageHeight              = 532
kMDItemPageWidth               = 370
kMDItemSecurityMethod          = "None"
kMDItemTitle                   = "Practical instruction in hypnotism and suggestion"
kMDItemUsedDates               = (
    "2013-10-16 00:00:00 -0700",
    "2013-10-17 00:00:00 -0700",
    "2013-10-30 00:00:00 -0700"
)
kMDItemVersion                 = "1.5"
```

In the OSX/Unix code, grep is being used to return the lines containing the height and width; awk is further formatting and outputting the lines of that output. All this could be done in AppleScript or AutoIt -- you don't really need grep and awk to do that. You just need to use AutoIt's string functions, like http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/StringSplit.htm

So, how to return the initial metadata? Maybe this would work (there may be others, but I'm needing to rush right now): http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-server/